# Extra cover on tefillin shel yad

Tags: tefilin

I've noticed that a lot of protective cases for the tefillin shel yad have an extra inner cover which slides out, usually a plastic cube with one side missing and a corner cut out for the knot, sometimes with a hole in the top.  Sometimes I've seen people leave this on the tefillin while wearing them.  Is there any religious significance to this object, or is there some reason that they are manufactured this way?  Is there any significance to leaving it on the tefillin while wearing it?

Comment: This was just asked yesterday https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/138562/759

Comment: I don't think so, I think that's referring to the main case - I'm talking about a thin box that is inserted into the main case

Comment: I mean into the main protective case

Comment: It is a duplicate of this one - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8350/why-does-the-tefilin-shel-yad-have-a-protective-cover not the one that it has been marked a duplicate of

Comment: i'm not sure what youre seeing here, they all look exactly the same to me